# Unable to view locally running node app on mobile device

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Totally new to node/express/mongo apps. I've got a basic one build running locally at `localhost:3000`. No issues running locally.

However, when I grab my macbook's IP (both Macbook and iPhone on the same wifi network) and attempt to navigate to my local port with it, nothing happens. It eventually times out.

`http://my.ip.address:3000` simply won't work on the mobile device.

What am I missing here?

Here's my server.js file if that's helpful.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var db

// MONGO

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:almighty@ds035348.mlab.com:35348/caseyappv1', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('View the build at http://localhost:3000/')
  })
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/index.ejs')
})
```

Comment: It sounds like there may be some network obstacles in your way. Some things to check: are you connecting the mobile device to local WiFi or trying to connect across regular cell data? Is the IP you're trying to connect to a private IP in your office or is it a public address from your IP? Are firewall rules/exceptions going to allow the connection to happen? Is IPv6 enabled on your host machine?

Answer (score 0):

Express uses the https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback under the hood.

You'll need to change app.listen to

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('View the build at http://localhost:3000/')
})
```